# Quantum Mechanics - Observable

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, observables

If $O$ represents an operator corresponding to an observable why does the following equality hold?

$$\langle f(x)\, |\,  O g(x)\rangle = \langle g(x) \,|\, O f(x) \rangle$$

It is used on the last step of the example on this page: http://www.chem.ufl.edu/~itl/4412/lectures/super_1.html

Is it because the expectation value of an observable has to be real and hence the above equality must hold?

Comment: If you read the next lecture, you'll see a complex conjucate appears: http://www.chem.ufl.edu/~itl/4412/lectures/super_2.html , so I guess it is a typo;)

Comment: Hi @msd27: Please include the complex conjucate $*$ in your equation. It is also mentioned in the third last formula on the page you link to.

Comment: @Qmechanic I thought this at first but if you look at the very last step on the page (between
(chem.ufl.edu/~itl/4412/lectures/super_1.htg/img14.gif) and(chem.ufl.edu/~itl/4412/lectures/super_1.htg/img15.gif) ) the identity without the complex conjugate has been used.

Comment: This is either caused by a typo or by an implicit assumption on that web page.

Answer (score 1):

You have omitted a complex conjugation, but the identity $$ \langle f \vert Og\rangle = \langle g | Of\rangle^* $$ holds because an observable by definition is Hermitian. An operator is Hermitian if $$(f , Og) = (Of ,g)$$
for all $f,g$. Since the inner product is conjugate-symmetric, $$(Of,g) = (g,Of)^*.$$

Comment: I also agree with you but do you know what has been done between these two steps:!(http://www.chem.ufl.edu/~itl/4412/lectures/super_1.htg/img14.gif) and !(http://www.chem.ufl.edu/~itl/4412/lectures/super_1.htg/img15.gif)

Comment: @robinekman If you read his link, that is not actually the case that he left out a star '*'. I had written the exact same answer, and then was checking over it before hitting 'add', and realised.
I want to say that the lecture is wrong in moving from the second last to the last line, no?

Comment: @robinekman I agree with the identity that you have put however it doesn't seem this is the on that had been used.

Comment: Also see this link: http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=PzA9tyP0YooC&pg=PA27&lpg=PA27&dq=superposition+state+expectation+value+observable&source=bl&ots=hQYvmk30fg&sig=UIGLcJ1UwLNR5iFRpxxRRQz4uCw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=BWNNU63uEYuGhQeu_IDoCg&ved=0CEkQ6AEwBA I am just not sure about how to get to the result proven.

Comment: If you keep the conjugation, you will end up with a some phase shift in the argument of the cosine. You can remove the phase shift by choosing $t=0$ when the expectation value is at a maximum.

Comment: @GeorgeG I don't follow how a cosine would still be able to be factored out?

Comment: Write it out. Any complex number can be written as $z=re^{i\theta}$, and its conjugate is $z^* = e^{-i\theta}$.

Comment: Oh, I thought you were referring to the equation following "Now, in general, the 'cross terms' do NOT VANISH, i.e."

Comment: @GeorgeG I don't think we will. The complex conjugation is referring to the inner product between the two states - this is the thing we are trying to factor out so we can express $exp(i(E1-E2)t/\hbar)+exp(-i(E1-E2)t/\hbar)$ as a cosine term - if we use the identity above then we can't factor out the inner product term.

Comment: @RobinEkman Apologies for not being clear enough. I have posted the two images as my first comment - I am just not sure how to get between the two. Do you have any idea how to?

Comment: You have $ze^{i\theta} + z^*e^{-i\theta}$. But $z = |z|e^{-i\varphi}$, so $z e^{i\theta} + z^* e^{-i\theta} = |z|(e^{i(\theta + \varphi)} + e^{-i(\theta +\varphi)}) = 2|z|\cos(\theta+\varphi)$.
You can adjust your zero time to drop the $\varphi$ phase shift. It seems that the page forgot an absolute value. Expectation values of observables should always be real so a complex term like $\langle \psi_1 | O |\psi_2 \rangle \cos(\theta)$ shouldn't appear.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, the equation as written is not quite correct, but lacks a complex conjugation.

The reason for this is a combination of the following three conditions:

- The expectation value of an observable $O$ when measured on state $|\psi\rangle$ is given by $\langle\psi|O\psi\rangle$.
- Observables always give real measurement values (and thus also real expectation values)
- The superposition principle: If $|\psi\rangle$ and $|\phi\rangle$ are valid quantum states, then also (normalized) superpositions of those states are valid quantum states.

Now consider the state $|\sigma\rangle =(|\psi\rangle+|\phi\rangle)/\sqrt2$. The expectation value of $O$ with this state is
$$\langle\sigma|O\sigma\rangle =
\tfrac12\left(\langle\psi|O\psi\rangle + \langle\psi|O\phi\rangle
+ \langle\phi|O\psi\rangle + \langle\phi|O\phi\rangle\right)$$
Since $\langle\sigma|O\sigma\rangle$, $\langle\psi|O\psi\rangle$ and $\langle\phi|O\phi\rangle$ are real, it follows that
$$\Im\left(\langle\psi|O\phi\rangle\right)=-\Im\left(\langle\phi|O\psi\rangle\right)$$
and by doing the same calculation with $(|\psi\rangle + \mathrm{i}|\phi\rangle)/\sqrt2$, you get
$$\Re\left(\langle\psi|O\phi\rangle\right)=\Re\left(\langle\phi|O\psi\rangle\right)$$
which together gives the condition
$$\langle\psi|O\phi\rangle = \langle\psi|O\phi\rangle^*$$
where $x^*$ denotes the complex conjugate of $x$.